# Manipulating Dialogflow intents/entities

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm creating a chatbot in Dialogflow in which the user is expected to enter a frequency of time, followed by specifying the time. i.e :

**Bot**: how many entries will you make on that day? (Or what so the frequency of your entries)?

**User**: Twice daily or two times a day.

**Bot**: Please enter those times.

**User**: 9 am and 7 pm

Now the problem is even if I enter more than two times it will still get accepted as the time by Dialogflow.

I need to implement a check here that will take only times if the user enters twice daily and accept three times if the frequency is thrice daily.

Is it possible to do this by manipulating entities and intents? I want to avoid doing this in the webhook.
Also the webhook I'll be implementing is in python. So can't use Node.js inline editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't be done in the Intents only. Remember that an Intent represents what the user has said, and not how you are using.

As you surmise, the best place to check these values are in your webhook fulfillment. Since you already have a webhook, it isn't clear why you are avoiding this.

In terms of design, you may wish to skip asking for the frequency and just ask the user to tell you when they'll be making the entries. You can then confirm that was all that they wanted, accept more if they needed more, etc.